# has anyone managed to create a Reverse DNS Zone on GCP -?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc, google-cloud-compute-engine

Just created a Reverse DNS Managed Zone as mentioned here - https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones/managed-reverse-lookup-zones - How do we add VM IPs ? with Terraform - Since the Reverse DNS Zone adds Networks to it - Wondering How will add PTR records to the Zone?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add records to a reverse lookup DNS zone directly; the data comes from the Compute Engine IP address data. Instead, add or modify the **Access Configuration** for the VM.

Note: You must first **verify ownership of the domain**. Ownership is verified in  [Webmaster Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home).

To create a DNS PTR record for an existing Compute Engine VM instance, use the command flag `--public-ptr`.

Examples:

```
gcloud compute instances add-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --public-ptr --public-ptr-domain [DOMAIN_NAME]
```

Use this command if the VM already has an access configuration:

```
gcloud compute instances update-access-config [INSTANCE_NAME] \
    --public-ptr --public-ptr-domain [DOMAIN_NAME]
```

[Creating a PTR Record for a VM Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-ptr-record)

Comment: So I added a PTR record for a VM and added it to a private DNS zone. Now if I just fetch DNS info using dig -x VM IP. It points to the hostname of the VM that was set using hostnamectl command. 
And if there is no hostname a reverse PTR lookup point to Cloud DNS internal address.

is this expected behaviour?

Comment: dig -x 10.154.0.2

; <<>> DiG 9.16.27-Debian <<>> -x 10.154.0.2
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44009
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;2.0.154.10.in-addr.arpa.       IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
2.0.154.10.in-addr.arpa. 300    IN      PTR     instance0.customhostname.

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Mon Aug 22 21:11:58 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 94

Comment: @UngabungaBoy22 - you are running dig inside the VM so it is querying the metadata server. Use dig from the Internet.